# Send data to a front-end application via node?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a node application that is hosting a self-contained front-end application in `/public` and a rest api. The front-end application communicates to the back-end exclusively via REST, but now I need to send some basic configuration information on the initial application load.

Rather than make an ajax request when the page loads, I would like to send down the required config information when `/index.html` is requested since it is necessary for the application to run.

What's the simplest way to setup some basic config?

Is there a way I can serve some script via node, and then parameterize it from the server?

Something like 
`/scripts/config.js`

```
angular.constant('value1', '#{some parameterized server value}');
```

I'm using express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a route that serves up the config.
Something like.

```
app.get('/scripts/config.js', function(req, res) {
  var content = 'angular.module(\'config\', [])\n';
  content += '  .constant(\'value1\', ' + someValue + ')';
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
  return res.send(content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it without making an Ajax request is include a config.json file in your index.html You can have node reading/writing your configuration properties to this file.

The order of execution in Angular is:

1. `app.config()`
2. `app.run()`
3. compile functions for directives
4. `app.controller`
5. directives linking

You can put your kickstarting logic in `app.config()` or `app.run()`.

I believe, the best practice though is separate your config logic in a module and use $http to fetch the properties dynamically.

Comment: Just a general comment.. unless something has changed recently you can't use $http in the app.config.. so unfortunately you can't use it to bootstrap the app. Even if you could, the app isn't going to wait around for a promise before hitting the run phase. If I'm wrong in this (and I would SO love to be), let me know.

Comment: You're not wrong, in fact you're absolutely right. That's why I never suggested using $http in `config()` nor in `run()` but rather in a separate module.

Comment: Right, right. Man, what a frustration. That little feature could make so much difference.. *sigh*